Unity: Character moves but it doesn't show
I'm making a 2D Platformer, Where the character is supposed to move right when I press the D key and left when i press the A key and it does move, the characters X position changes correctly in the inspector. However, When i put a BG image to test it, The BG image stays still. The space bar doesn't do anything either. I'm fairly new to unity.
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == true)
{
    rigidBody.velocity = UnityEngine.Vector2.right * 5 * Time.deltaTime; 
}  
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) == true)
{
    rigidBody.velocity = UnityEngine.Vector2.left * 5 * Time.deltaTime;
}  
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) == true)
{
    rigidBody.velocity = UnityEngine.Vector2.up * 5 * Time.deltaTime; 
}  
       if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == true)
{
    rigidBody.transform.localScale = new UnityEngine.Vector2(transform.localScale.x,  (float)0.5);
} 
    else{
        rigidBody.transform.localScale = new UnityEngine.Vector2(transform.localScale.x, 1);
    } 
    }
}


I am expecting it to move w.r.t to the bg image, and the space bar to work.
Here is the Camera Script if necessary:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x + 6, player.position.y, -10);
    }
}

Player is set to the character.

This might be very helpful: https://gameartist86.medium.com/simple-player-movement-in-unity-2d-c9bfd46f8837

@Kroepniek That worked fantastic! Thank you so much!

part of your issue is you are resetting velocity in update, not fixedupdate, as well as dependant on the key, overwriting verlicity with another direction

is your bg image you are testing this on maybe in screen pixel space? In that space 5 per second is rather very little ...

@BugFinder setting velocity from Update is not an issue - the next physics routine will simply apply the latest known velocity so setting it in FixedUpdate would have the very same effect actually - the overruling part though is at best very bad UX ^^

@derHugo I was always told velocity in update is not accurate. Hence should only be checked and altered in fixed update

It's work fine for me. I can check it in the inspector. but movement is too small.
I change this
rigidBody.velocity = UnityEngine.Vector2.right * 5 * Time.deltaTime; 

to this
rigidBody.velocity = UnityEngine.Vector2.right * 1000 * Time.deltaTime; 

I hope this helps.
